# Java Networking Server, protocol and client

Tags: java

I have this multi server thread, so whenever the 'X' button is click on the top right hand corner, i want to display the message "closing the socket" on the server side.

```
public void run
{

  try
  {
    // .....
     String inputLine, outputLine;
    Protocol p = new Protocol();
    outputLine = p.processInput(null, p);
    out.println(outputLine);

   while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    outputLine = p.processInput(inputLine,p);
    out.println(outputLine);
    if (outputLine.equals("Bye"))
            {
                System.out.print("Closing socket.");
                break;
            }
    }


    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();
 catch (IOException e)
 {
    // .....
  }

}

public String processInput(String theInput, Protocol p) 
 {
     theOutput = null;


     frame = new JFrame ("Find The Word!");
      frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
              theOutput = "Bye";
        }
    });

    frame.add(p);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);





    return theOutput;
}
```

But it doesn't work, and i have to manually end the process for the server side. I assume that it got stuck at the while loop, but i couldn't figure out whats wrong with it.

Comment: What is in the listener of your button?

Comment: you cant add a listener to the window buttons. it is handled correctly with a WindowAdapter.

Comment: So that it will return "Bye", in order to break the while loop inside the server?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't induce the server to send you a Bye messages, you can drop out of the loop as if it had sent you a Bye message or close the socket from another thread.